# Problems with error code when writing to core data with Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I am new to coding with Swift and I am trying to write two text fields into my core data file.  I have figured out most of the code I need by searching on line but I am getting an error that I can't figure out.  I have posted the entire save function code below but I am getting a "Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'NSManagedObjectContext'" error on the line starting with managedObjectContext.

```
@IBAction func saveData(sender: AnyObject) {
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("MatchData", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    let matchData = MatchData(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    matchData.teamNumber = teamNumber.text
    matchData.matchNumber = matchNumber.text

    var error: NSError?

    managedObjectContext?.save(error)

    if let err = error {
        status.text = err.localizedFailureReason
    } else {
        teamNumber.text = ""
        matchNumber.text = ""
    }
}
```

I am working with the newest version of Xcode and I think the issue has something to with the changes in Swift but I can't figure it out since I am a novice.  Any help debugging would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the `do, try, catch` statement? If you want to save objects to the `managedObjectContext` you must be use this statement like so:`do { try manaagedObjectContext.save() } catch { // handle error
}`

Please try this out! Hope it helps

`@IBAction func saveData(sender: AnyObject) {

let entityDescription:MatchData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MatchData", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! MatchData

```
entityDescription.teamNumber = self.teamNumber.text
entityDescription.matchNumber = self.matchNumber.text

do { try managedObjectContext.save() } catch { /*Handle error*/  }
```

print(entityDescription)
}`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of how to structure the code.  I had tried using do, try and catch but couldn't figure out how to implement it.

Comment: Thanks.  This really helped.

Comment: If this helpful? Please accept this answer:) Thanks for your attention! Good luck